# CollectionViewCell, custom cell, autolayout constraints with multiline

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

I have storyboard with custom cell, I have 3 views on my custom cell but one of the view causing a problem, `UILabel` **with 2 line support**. I use `W:Any-H:Any` and create a constraits to a label like this (now, to elimiate all the issues - i'm connecting it to superviews, not to views nearest, but error still occurs):

1. Leading Space to Superview
2. Trailing Space to Superview
3. Top Space to Superview

So it looks like this:

[image]

If I remove constraints from this view I'm not getting error so error must be from this.

And then i get constraints error:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe1d3df4e80 UILabel:0x7fe1d3df7730'Autos, Roller, Fahrr\U00e4der,...'.trailing == UIView:0x7fe1d7a33140.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe1d3df4ed0 H:|-(70)-[UILabel:0x7fe1d3df7730'Autos, Roller, Fahrr\U00e4der,...']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fe1d7a33140 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fe1d3dbb1c0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7fe1d7a33140(50)]>"
)
```

What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: The last line looks like, for some reason, the cell's `contentView` wants to be 50 points wide, but you're trying to position the label 70 points from the left and its trailing equal to the `contentView`'s trailing margin. Are you willing to do pure auto layout in code? If so, I can help you construct your cell. I've transitioned to this approach to avoid just such irritating problems such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the priority of Trailing Space to 999 is a simple workaround, but I cannot explain how this fixes that.

It appears that Trailing Space (1st constraint in the error) constraint conflicts with constraint which is translated from the autoresizing mask of contentView (3rd constraint) and this workaround resolves it.